# Check if the user is purchasing an IAP with a different Apple ID that he bought/got the APP?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I would like to insert that rule in my app like IK Multimedia does in its own apps (i.e. VocalLive, Amplitube, etc.)

Infact if you get one of their APP with an Apple ID, you can't restore IAP with an other account by changing the Apple ID in iPad iTunes settings.

All ideas are appreciated

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296750/payment-applicationusername-in-ios-7-storekit-for-in-app-purchases